# encountering errors while adding a foreign key in models.py

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I wanted to migrate some models but the ones with the foreignkey functions are causing some problems.

I ran the following code and it caused an error

```sh
python manage.py migrate
```

and the foreign key  seems the problem

```py
class Webpage(models.Model):   
    topic =models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264 , unique=True)
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\helin\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\sitepackages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\helin\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
        autoreload.raise_last_exception()
 File "C:\Users\helin\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
        raise _exception[1]
 File "C:\Users\helin\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
 File "C:\Users\helin\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\sitepackages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\helin\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
 File "C:\Users\helin\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
        app_config.import_models()
 File "C:\Users\helin\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
        self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
 File "C:\Users\helin\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 697, in exec_module
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
 File "C:\Users\helin\Downloads\my_django\first_project\first_app\models.py", line 12, in <module>
        class Webpage(models.Model):
 File "C:\Users\helin\Downloads\my_django\first_project\first_app\models.py", line 13, in Webpage
        topic =models.ForeignKey(Topic)
 TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

Comment: What is unclear about that error? ForeignKeys need an `on_delete` parameter, as [clearly documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#arguments).

Comment: what is 'on_delete'?.....my instructor did not need to add that phrase for his code to work properly

Comment: Did you look at the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'.

When using foreign key, you need to pass 'on_delete' argument to it. This will make sure that whenever the table/ record to which this foreign key is a primary key is deleted it will automatically delete/protect the record of the table where it acts as a foreign key.

Example:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_id = <something>
class Account(models.Model):
    customer_id = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

So, when a customer with customer_id = x is deleted in Customer related table, it will delete the corresponding record in the Account table.

You can read about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#arguments)